# What is the function of the "Shape Object" tool in particle edit mode?

Tags: particles

There's little video tutorials on particle edit mode. I would like to know what this tool does.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/mode.html#id3) it

> trims hairs to a shape defined by the Shape Object

That means it allows you to create a mesh that surrounds all or part of your model and use it to cut hair that goes outside that mesh.

Increasing the path steps under it also helps give better results.